# Azure Queue in Local Azure Storage Explorer returning RESTERROR when adding a new message

Tags: azure-storage-emulator, azure-storage-explorer

The local storage Account Queue returning "RESTERROR" popup when adding a new message(and message not getting added).

[image]

I am able to add message to my other subscription Queues in the Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below points to see if it is your case :

- Following the doc [Use the Azure Storage Emulator for development
  and testing (deprecated) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator).

  That error message sometimes means you got either your account name
  or account key wrong. So if you attached with name and key or a
  connection string, please confirm you typed your account name right
  and see  if key you are using is up to date.
- The service endpoints for the Storage Emulator are different from the
  endpoints for an Azure storage account. The local computer doesn't do
  domain name resolution, requiring the Storage Emulator endpoints to
  be local addresses.
- The account name maybe the part of the URI path instead of the host
  name even in local address.

  The service endpoint for the Storage Emulator for local computer
  Queue service is:
  `http://127.0.0.1:10001/<account-name>/<resource-path` We may some
  times need to change this when using for local storage as it may not
  have resolved by itself which may result in error.
- Also check if the storage emulator version is compatible and local
  storage has enough space to add. Try to re install the storage
  emulator with latest version.

Check the bug fixes/changes in versions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#storage-emulator-release-notes).

Also check [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer Unable To Retrieve Child Resources (findes.co)](https://foxtutor.findes.co/microsoft-azure-storage-explorer-unable-to-retrieve-child-resources/) which can be helpful to troubleshoot error in few cases.

**Note:** From microsoft docs

> The **Azure Storage Emulator is now deprecated**. Microsoft recommends
> that you use the Azurite emulator for local development with Azure
> Storage. So you can use azure functions with azurite emulator to add
> or do operations on queue or messages

See :[Tutorial-how to create azure queue messages and debug with azure storage emulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RoWTraIo-A)   for guidance.